# Test-Path -isValid with wildcards

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to validate paths so I can provide meaningful error logging, and I am running into an issue with wildcards.
This returns False unless there is a folder and something in it, but it should return True.

```
Test-Path -isValid -path:"C:\Somefolder\*"
```

And like this doesn't work because -literalPath doesn't interpret wildcards.

```
Test-Path -isValid -literalPath:"C:\Somefolder\*"
```

My sense is that I am going to have to test for wildcards, and if found `Test-Path -isValid` on the parent folder. But then I run into issues with `-like` because I can't really test for a condition like *.EXT. Which has me thinking the only real answer is a RegEx, but this feels like something so basic I shouldn't really need to resort to a RegEx and I am probably missing something.
Note that for a variety of reasons I am limited to PS v2.

EDIT: To clarify, the actual path is variable. Users provide a path in an XML file, I then validate the path and do something with it. So, it might be that the user wants to delete all TXT files in a certain path. Or all files. Or even all files and subfolders. Thus **C:\Somefolder\*** needs to be supported. If they had **C:\\Somefolder\*** or **C:Somefolder\*** I would want to flag that as an invalid path. But **C:\Somefolder\*** when Somefolder doesn't exist is not an invalid path, it's a missing folder and I want to flag that as a different error.

Comment: What path do you want to test? Is `Test-Path "C:\Somefolder"` good enough?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need a regular expression for validating a path specification. Something like this should work:

```
$re = '^[a-z]:[/\\][^{0}]*$' -f [regex]::Escape(([IO.Path]::InvalidPathChars -join ''))
'C:\something\*' -match $re   # returns $true
```

The expression will match any string starting with a letter followed by a colon, a forward or backslash, and any number of valid path characters.

Note that consecutive path separators are valid in a path, so `C:\\something\* -match $re` will evaluate to `$true` as well, as it should.

If you want to validate actual (existing) paths instead of path specs you can use `Get-ChildItem`:

```
function Test-WildcardPath($Path) {
  Get-ChildItem $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue >$null
  return $?
}
```

Again, `C:\\something\*` will evaluate to `$true`, since consecutive path separators are allowed in a path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this :

```
Test-Path -IsValid C:\Somefolder
```

Edit : then why don't you leave out the wildchars for test-path?

```
$test.Substring(0,($test.length-($test.Split("\")[-1]).length-1))
```

Comment: Milan and Andrey, see the revised OP. In this case I must support the wildcards, so C:\Somefolder is not an option. As I said, I suspect I will end up testing exactly this because I will have to test for valid wild cards, and when I find them I then Test-Path on the parent folder. On that front I think I can use -like with escaped wildcards.